# Is a foreground service is treated as though it were running in background (i.e. is its resource utilization limited)

Tags: android, react-native

Does anybody know if a foreground service on Android is treated as though it were running in background (i.e. is its resource utilization limited)... or is it treated like it is actually running in the foreground?  I am trying to use a foreground service to get around processes being throttled by Android when I am in background.  According to docs, if battery optimizations are removed, I can start a foreground service from the background.  What it does not say is if the foreground service would then execute as though it were a background service or not.

I got a foreground service executing... it appears to be operating at a slower pace than it would in the foreground.  I just want to verify that it is suppose to be that way.  i.e. the foreground task is actually run in the background.

Comment: The speed a process runs at is utterly uneffected by foreground/background.  Unless you have so many things going on your device that every CPU is pegged at 100% and your process is CPU bound, then when you're scheduled to run you'll run at the same speed.  In reality, mobile devices are pretty much never limited by processing time.

Comment: Interesting..... I am defiantly seeing a difference in running the same service in foreground vs background.  There are 2 data processing aspects of the app.  The first is issuing fetches every 3 seconds and processing the response (simple response... basically just taking the information for 1 stock and putting it in an async database).  The second is issuing 2 large queries.  These queries get a close price and current price for 11K stocks.

Comment: Then the app goes into a loop to update date database with each value.  When I run the app in the foreground, the first processing aspect (the query every 3 seconds) seems to be unaffected.  The second query aspect seems to take a lot longer.  In foreground the 2 large queries can be processed in an hour.  In background it takes about 8 hours..... any thoughts?